# WebFlux call with WebClient returning IllegalStateException Only one connection receive subscriber allowed

Tags: rest, kotlin, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm using Webflux and WebClient to talk to another API

```
suspend fun doSomething() : myResponse {
    return webClient
      .get()
      .uri {
        it.path("/some/path")
          .queryParam("activeOnly", true)
          .build()
      }
      .retrieve()
      .onStatus(
        { httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND == httpStatus },
        { throw CustomException("my message") }
      )
      .bodyToMono(responseType)
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout))
      .onErrorResume { ex ->
        when (ex) {
          is CustomException-> Mono.fromCallable { emptyList<MyResponse>() }
          else -> Mono.error(ex)
        }
      }
      .doOnError { ex ->
        handleTimeoutException(
          exception = ex,
          endPoint = "some endpoint"
        )
      }
}

suspend fun doSomethingElse() : anotherResponse { .. } // calls a different endpoint
```

Both functions share the same WebClient and are called in another class -

```
val foo = myClientClass.doSomething().awaitFirst()
val bar = myClientClass.doSomethingElse().awaitFirst()
```

I am not explictly using `.subscribe()`anywhere

I'm seeing this in my logs -

> IllegalStateException Only one connection receive subscriber allowed: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.', hint: 'null' |
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext

I don't believe I'm resubscribing to the response body ... correct me if I'm wrong.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong in my get call that would cause this?

Comment: From the first look there is nothing wrong with `WebClient`here. Please share the call stack and more info regarding subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Only one connection receive subscriber allowed* is the key here.
In my code, if I had:

```
.onStatus

.bodyToMono

.onErrorResume
```

I found that meant that more subscribers were trying to receive the response, thus causing the problem.
Try to simplify everything by switching to kotlin *coroutines*, you will see the error go away:

```
suspend fun doSomething() : myResponse {
    return webClient
      .get()
      .uri {
        it.path("/some/path")
          .queryParam("activeOnly", true)
          .build()
      }
      .awaitExchange { clientResponse ->
        when (clientResponse.statusCode()) {
            NOT_FOUND -> emptyList<MyResponse>()
            OK -> clientResponse.awaitBody<List<MyResponse>>()
            else -> throw clientResponse.createExceptionAndAwait()
        }
    }
```

Timeout is not part of your actual problem here, so I did not include it in the answer, but if you want to handle it, you can use a simple `flow`.

To make this work, check you have the follow dependencies: `kotlinx-coroutines-core` and `kotlinx-coroutines-reactor`.